# Share transaction in FireDAC between DLLs

Tags: delphi, firedac

I'd like to share FireDAC transaction between Application/DLL and DLL. When share connection ( like there: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/DLL_Development_(FireDAC) ) the default(?) transaction shares too. But how to share other transaction keep by TFDTransaction component? There's no any handle (like in TIBTransaction or in TFDConnection). How to do this?

Comment: `FDTransaction.TransactionIntf.CliObj` gives you a pointer to the physical transaction object. Or you can share directly the `TransactionIntf` interface reference.

Comment: thx Victoria. But it is possible to assign this data to TFDTransaction component, or I can use IFDPhysTransaction only from now (in DLL)?

Comment: That `CliObj` you can cast to the physical transaction object, e.g. `TIBTransaction(SharedCliObj)..`. Or, as you say, share the physical transaction interface.

Comment: So in DLL I call DLLFunc(FDTransaction1.TransactionInf.CliObj) and in DLL FDTransaction2 := TFDTransaction(aDLLParam)? That can't work... Can You write some sample code? I don't wont pass whole component too - it require to version of component same both sites. But with default transaction (from TFDConnection) this can work. Why can't TFDConnection connect to existing transacion?

Comment: In other words - how I can get my own TFDTransaction object (need f.ex. as parameter for functions) attached to existing transaction? And pass to DLL two active transactions (not only default for connection).

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific before. I meant, that a physical transaction object will have some shareable handle (e.g. the mentioned `TIBTransaction` has `FTRHandle`). But in this case I think there should be no problem to share the `IFDPhysTransaction` interface.

Comment: But this still not same as component (based on IFDPhysTransactionStateHandler - IFDPhysTransaction is only read-only field of TFDCustomTransaction). I don't like to change all procedures, where pass transaction as parameter. Now use IBEx components, where are simple SetHandle for transaction (protected, but is there and works very simple). In TIBTransaction is some like CreateUsingHandle but... How to make this usefull for me?